# Cannot add nameservers to DirectAdmin

Tags: directadmin

I moved to a new server, but can't figure how to add nameservers to DirectAdmin. It's quite a mess using DirectAdmin. cpanel is much simpler.

I have 1 main server IP. And 3 nameserver IP's, I found with `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

My current hosting provider doesn't allow adding domains. Only I if I fully transfer my domains to them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add your additional ip to `dns management` or `dns administration` for each ip make an `A record` the value is for `exmaple` `ns1` , `ns2` & etc and other field is for yor ips.
and the end service dns must be reset with this command :
`service dns restart;`

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you mean

If you mean the nameserver for **DNS** that you added in the right place.

If your name server is the same as **NS**, you can:
[Directadmin DNS update](https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=141)

Comment: Please use comments to ask for clarifications of the question instead of answers.